# Unable to upload files to S3 , Access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am running an EC2 instance (with an IAM role which got AmazonS3FullAccess), now I am running a nodejs server in it and trying to upload a file to s3 bucket (public access) but getting Access Denied 403 Error.
Since the EC2 got S3 access, didn't provide accessKey/secret in node
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-iam.html

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
  const params = {
        Bucket: 'sample_name', // pass your bucket name
        Key: 'filename',
        Body: "<p>Hey</p>",
        ContentDisposition: 'inline',
        ContentType: 'text/html',
    };
    s3.upload(params, function (s3Err, data) {
        if(s3Err) throw s3Err;
        console.log(data)
    })
```

could someone please help me on this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you double check the bucket name and make sure you are the bucket owner?

Comment: What does your S3 object key look like? If it's of the form `/dogs/akita.png` then that's the problem. It should be `dogs/akita.png`.

Comment: @jellycsc ,  Ya checked that is a public bucket

Comment: @jarmod, the key is just the filename like akita.png

Comment: Does the bucket have  bucket policy? What is in it? The bucket might, for example, have a policy requiring the uploader to indicate ACL: "bucket-owner-full-control" or to require the uploader to request encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your bucket permissions and check if there are any permissions there or not. If not then add these, it might work!

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```